# Crashlytics automatic upload of dsym files

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I have the following build setup in XCode:

[image]

I need to understand if this build script will be running every-time I build and upload a new dsym file to Crashlytics server? Or it will run only when there are version or code changes I make?

Answer (score 3):

- The second line "upload-symbols" is not necessary.
- It uploads every time the dsym changes
- Make sure that in your target's build settings, Debug information Format is se to DWARF with dSYM for both debug and release

Comment: Actually, the script doesn't upload dSym unless I force a crash in the code. Had to manually upload the dSyms despite the Run Script commands!

Comment: Dsym is uploaded at build time. Crashing the application can’t trigger it. If you set the third point correctly, it should upload as it does in all of my projects. The Firebase console is sluggish and lags so you may have to do some project  lean and rebuild plus waiting for some minutes before it is handled correctly.

Comment: @TomoNorbert I am making sure to follow the third point but it always asks in Firebase Crashlytic Console to manually upload dsym